# Improve MySQL query efficiency for first row in a group

Tags: mysql, query-performance, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I've written the query below in MySQL to get the top 10 top landing pages across all browser sessions.

Reading other similar posts about how to access the first row in a group, it seemed like the solution was the following:

```
SELECT MIN(`created_at`) AS `created_at`, `session_token`, `url`
FROM `session`
GROUP BY `session_token`;
```

This produced incorrect results and I found that while using `MIN()` to get the first record in a group, it only applied to the specified column and that other columns could be picked from other rows within the group.

I amended the query to the one below which produces the correct result:

```
SELECT `b`.`created_at`, `b`.`session_token`, `b`.`url` 
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(`created_at`) AS `created_at`, `session_token`, `url` 
    FROM `session` 
    GROUP BY `session_token`
) a
INNER JOIN `session` b USING (`session_token`, `created_at`);
```

I've created the solution below that produces the correct results, however it is now using two subqueries.

```
SELECT `c`.`url`, COUNT(*) AS `hits` 
FROM (
    SELECT `b`.`created_at`, `b`.`session_token`, `b`.`url` 
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN(`created_at`) AS `created_at`, `session_token`, `url` 
        FROM `session` 
        GROUP BY `session_token`
    ) `a`
    INNER JOIN `session` `b` USING (`session_token`, `created_at`)
) AS `c`
GROUP BY `c`.`url`
ORDER BY `hits` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I've only tested it on a small dataset and it doesn't seem particularly fast. Could it be improved to increase efficiency?

Comment: Does the index `(session_token, created_at, url)` exists?

Comment: No, I've but I've just added that key and now it returns the correct result.

Comment: Execution time is improved by about 0.003 seconds on average on the small test data.

Comment: See the tag I added and/or http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max